# Qprocess subprocess.completed signal not triggering PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I have a Pyside6 app that is supposed to run a subprocess as part of it's functioning. When the subprocess finishes it is supposed to trigger the signal `self.subprocess.finished`, but the function `notify_success_or_failure` is not being run, even after the process finishes.

this is my code

```
    def begin_subprocess(self, folder_path, return_to_path, return_path):
        self.subprocess = QProcess()
        # check what command needs to be run to start the subprocess
        python_executable = sys.executable

        # gather the parameters needed
        paramaters = [folder_path, str(return_to_path), return_path]
        command_info = [python_executable, "./true_run.py"]
        command = command_info + paramaters

        print(command)
        
        # Connect the finished signal of the QProcess to the custom signal
        self.subprocess.finished.connect(self.notify_success_or_failure)
        
        # Start the subprocess asynchronously
        self.subprocess.startDetached(command[0], command[1:])
```

I would like to be able to say I have tried a few things, but I haven't been able to. I have no clue what is causing the problem, probobly a lack of know-how, if someone here knows more than me about pyside that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `startDetached`, as the name suggests, starts a new *detached* process. Meaning that you will obviously get no signals at all.

Comment: Oh, I figured it would be something like that, I meant that it ran asynchronously but interactively in the terminal, thanks.

Comment: Terminal interaction is irrelevant, that's how eventually each process can access terminal features, and it's not like "it disables signals": it's a completely independent process, for which Qt "releases" its control, unlike when having it internally managed through the QObject API. May I ask you what you are trying to achieve and why you want to start a detached process while still attempting to "access" it?

Comment: I didn't realize what detached meant I guess, detached allowed me to interact with the program, which runs ffmpeg, ffmpeg is sometimes interactive in the terminal and produces logs which are useful for debugging. I liked that feature, but in the end I don't think that it proved to be needed.

Comment: If you need to keep track of the output, you don't need to detach the process, instead connect to its `readyRead...` signals and read its stdout/stderr output buffers. You can also interact with the process by directly writing to it. Read the QProcess documentation more carefully and look for related posts here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was using the wrong kind of start method, I made the mistake of thinking that startDetached would start it in the terminal and allow the user to interact with the program (which it does on the side). in the end, it turns out that `startDetatched` disabled signals, thanks musicamante.